# What is the best way to treat labelled variables imported with haven?

Tags: r, r-haven

I have about 15 SPSS election studies files saved as .sav files. My group and I will be recoding about 10 variables for each study to run some logistic regressions.

I have used `haven()` to import all the files, so it looks like all the variables are of the `haven_labelled()` class.

I have always been a little confused about how to handle this class of variables, however I have observed a lot of improved performance as the haven() and labelled() packages have been updated, so I'm inclined to keep using it as opposed to using, e.g. `rio` or `foreign`.

But I want to get a sense of what best practices should be *before* we start this effort so we don't look back with regret.

Each study file has about 200 variables, with a mix of factors and numeric variables. But to start, I'm wondering how I should go about recoding the sex variable so that I end up with a variable `male` where 1 is male and 0 is not.

One thing I want to ask about is the `car::Recode()` method of recoding variables as opposed to the `dplyr::recode` variable way. I personally find the `dplyr::recode()` syntax very clunky and the help documentation poor. I am also not sure about the best way to set missing values.

To be specific, I think I have three specific questions.

Question 1: is there a compelling reason to use `dplyr::recode` as opposed to `car::Recode`? My own answer is that `car::Recode()` looks sufficient and easy to use.

Question 2: Should I make a point of converting variables to factors or numeric or will I be OK, leaving variables as haven_labelled with updated value labels? I am concerned about this quote from the haven documentation about the `labelled_class`: ''This class provides few methods, as I expect you’ll coerce to a standard R class (e.g. a `factor()`) soon after importing''

However, maybe the `haven_labelled` class has been improved and is sufficiently different from the labelled class that it is no longer necessary to force conversion to other standard R classes.

Question 3: is there any advantage to setting missing values with the `labelled` (e.g. `na_range()`, `na_values()`) rather than with the `car::Recode()` method ?

My inclination is that there clear disadvantages to using the `labelled` methods and I should stick with the `car::Recode()` method.

Thank you .

```
#FAKE DATA
library(labelled)
var1<-labelled(rep(c(1,5), 100), c(male = 1, female = 5))
var2<-labelled(sample(c(1,3,5,7,8,9), size=200, replace=T), c('strongly agree'=1, 'agree'=3, 'disagree'=5, 'strongly disagree'=7, 'DK'=8, 'refused'=9))
#give variable labels
var_label(var1)<-'Respondent\'s sex'
var_label(var2)<-'free trade is a good thing'
df<-data.frame(var1=var1, var2=var2)
str(df)
#This works really well; and I really like this. 
look_for(df, 'sex')
look_for(df, 'free trade')
#the Car way
df$male<-car::Recode(df$var1, "5=0")
#Check results
df$male 
#value labels are still there, so would have to be removed or updated
as_factor(df$male)
#Remove value labels
val_labels(df$male)<-NULL
#Check 
class(df$male) #left with a numeric variable
#The other car way, keeping and modifying value labels
df$male2<-car::Recode(df$var1, "5=0")
df$male2
val_label(df$male2, 0)<-c('female')
val_label(df$male2, 5)<-NULL
val_labels(df$male2)
#Check class
class(df$male2)
#Can run numeric functions on it
mean(df$male2)
#easily convert to factor
as_factor(df$male2)

#How to handle missing values
#The CAR way
#use car to set missing values to NA
df$free_trade<-Recode(df$var2, "8=NA; 9=NA")
#Check class
class(df$free_trade)
#can still run numeric functions on haven_labelled
mean(df$free_trade, na.rm=T)
#table
table(df$free_trade)
#did the na recode work?
table(is.na(df$free_trade))
#check value labels
val_labels(df$free_trade)   

#How to handle missing values
#The CAR way
#use car to set missing values to NA
df$free_trade<-Recode(df$var2, "8=NA; 9=NA")
#Check class
class(df$free_trade)
#can still run numeric functions on haven_labelled
mean(df$free_trade, na.rm=T)
#table
table(df$free_trade)
#did the na recode work?
table(is.na(df$free_trade))
#check value labels
val_labels(df$free_trade)      

#set missing values the labelled way
table(df$var2)
na_values(df$var2)<-c(8,9)
#check
df$var2
#but a table function of does not pick up 8 and 9 as m isisng
table(df$var2)
#this seems to not work very well
table(to_factor(df$var2))
to_factor(df$var2)
```

Comment: haven 2.2.0 uses the the [forcats](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/) package - might be worth looking into the functions in that package that might help with your needs

Answer (score 0):

A bit late in the game, but still some answers:

> Should I make a point of converting variables to factors or numeric or will I be OK, leaving variables as haven_labelled with updated value labels?

First, you need to understand that haven_labelled vectors are all of numeric type (i.e. they will be treated as continuous variables), which you can easily check with:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  head()
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
        var1                  var2
   <dbl+lbl>             <dbl+lbl>
1 1 [male]   5 [disagree]         
2 5 [female] 5 [disagree]         
3 1 [male]   3 [agree]            
4 5 [female] 5 [disagree]         
5 1 [male]   7 [strongly disagree]
6 5 [female] 9 [refused]
```

The question if you shoudl convert to a standard type probably depends on your analysis.

For simple frequency tables it's probably fine to leave as is, e.g.

```
df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  count(var1)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
        var1     n
   <dbl+lbl> <int>
1 1 [male]     100
2 5 [female]   100
```

However, for any analysis that is type sensitive (already starts for calculating means, but also regression etc.) you definitely should convert your variables to an appropriate class for your analyses. Not doing so and treating everything as continuous will give your wrong results. Just think about a truly categorical variable like 1=Bus, 2=Car, 3=Bike that you'd throw into a linear regression.

---

> Is there a compelling reason to use dplyr::recode as opposed to car::Recode?

There is now right or wrong here. Personally, I have a preference for staying within the `tidyverse`, because it has easy recode functions, e.g. the `recode` you mentioned, but for more complex tasks, you can also use `if_else` or `case_when`. And then you also have lots of functions to deal with missings like `replace_na` or `na_if` or `coalesce`. They syntax of `car::recode` isn't much different from the dplyr, so it's really mostly personal preference I'd say.

The same is true for your question if you should use the functions from `labelled` or not. The `labelled` packages indeed adds some very powerful functions to deal with labelled vectors taht go beyond what `haven` or the `tidyverse` offers, so IMO it's a good package to use.